# render received emails in rails, gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, render, incoming-mail

I want to render received emails (via SMTP Server) that are stored in my DB and my question is:

- Is there a gem that provides rendering html_part, text_part from incoming email (received via SMTP Server) or something that can help to render an email depending which type it is (HTML, TEXT) ?

with best regards 
Hannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a very beautiful gem [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) here [github link](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher)
Instructions:

1) install the gem configure it by replacing your default setting with

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }
```

2) open terminal type mailcatcher enter.

3) send email.

4) now open browser and go to this address `localhost:1080`.

you will see that you have received email.

Comment: I´ve found the same gem, but thats to much for my case. I just need a gem that can render a mail object from an action mailer to proper html into as an partial. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[MailView](https://github.com/basecamp/mail_view) from 37signals allows you to render Mailer objects and view them from your browser.